# Omniauth Twitter fails with session_expired error

Tags: twitter, sinatra, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I have started building a small app and using Omniauth and the omniauth-twitter gems.

Everyhting is going fine until twitters hits the callback url and i get sent to the failure response with the error `auth/failure?message=session_expired&strategy=twitter`.

Here is my code so far:

```
class Admin < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Namespace
  enable :sessions

  use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :twitter, 'Cient_ID', 'Client_secret'
  end

  namespace '/admin' do
    get do
      erb :index
    end

    get '/login/?' do
      redirect '/auth/twitter'
    end

 end

 get '/auth/twitter/callback' do
   "You are now logged in"
 end
end
```

When i go to `/admin/login` I get redirect to twitter asking me to authorize the app and when I click "Allow" it redirects me back but I just get sent to the same failure screen over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out in my case. I was using Pow as my web server and in my project folder had a folder called 'tmp'. You can tell POW to restart the server on every request by adding in a file called 'always_restart'. The fact that the server restarted on every request meant the the session token became invalid. By removing this file I got it to work.

Comment: I had been stuck on a little side project for weeks because I couldn't figure out for the life of me why it wasn't working locally. This was it. Thank you! Automatically restarting on request is great, except for when it's not.